# Phprunner the event code on changin row background color

Tags: php

I know there is a forum for this issue but seems like WOT has warned something. Don't know exactly what is happening to the site but hope some guys out there can help me since no one answered my question there.

[image]

**Main Problem:**

Here is my code on List Page: After record processed event

```
     if (strtoupper($data["Availability"]) =="SOLD"){   
    $row["rowstyle"]='style="background:red; color:white"';
}
```

I even tried to print the value of "Availability" inside the condition and it prints exactly as SOLD but seems like nothing happened.

**NOTE This is important:**

I can see that the row background changes when refreshed or during few seconds of loading (SEEMS WORKING!) but after that the color gets back to its original settings.

Hope anyone can tell me that this is a bug or am I really missing something.

References: PhpRunner Manual and http://xlinesoft.com/blog/2011/01/03/tutorial_conditional_formatting/

Comment: What is the HTML output you are getting?

Comment: @cryptic The final output is in table <tr style="color:#333; background:white" etc....> w/c is the original or default settings. My code is to make the color white and background to red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. thanks
**Dont check** 'Resizable table columns' on Miscellaneous page under 'Table Specific Settings'. Not a great answer though, but solves my issue.